# How can I do to put multiple clickable points on the image?

Tags: android, image, google-maps, coordinates, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an image with a map of principal subway in my country. I need that the users can press the stations on image of the map.

My question is, **How can I do to put multiple clickable points on the image?** These points will be the subway stations.

I find per several hours, but I do not see anything specific.

I searched for many hours and I found these posts:

1.- This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020612/place-image-at-coordinates-android) maybe resolver my question, but is very old, This makes me think that there is some more updated functionality.

2.- In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255433/google-maps-coordinates-to-perspective-map-image-coordinates) says that you can use *"GoogleMap object and ground overlay"* but I found the oficial documentation about [Ground Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple?hl=es-419) topic and the image with the map is not alone, the image has background google map.

Does anyone know if there is a current tool with which I can solve this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put transparent buttons on top of your imageview at the positions where you want to option a click using a relative layout and then just handle the button clicks.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@android:drawable/edit_text" />

 <Button android:id="@+id/bottomLeft" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

 <Button android:id="@+id/center" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="@android:color/transparent" /> 

<Button android:id="@+id/bottomRight" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhriya Roy but, Do you think this solution works when you zoom in on the map image, and for about 60 different clicks are the stations?